# Passing Object Between ViewModel using Caliburn.Micro 2.0.0 alpha2

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

i'm developing a simple application (Windows Store Application) i got some data from sqlite which i want to manage.
Using caliburn.Micro 2.0.0 i'm trying to develop using mvvm pattern.

I developed ListView and ListViewModel ,  DetailView and DetailViewModel.

The ListView shows a listbox of person (taken from db) and i want to show the details when each row is selected.

The problems are

1. How can i navigate from ListViewModel to DetailViewModel with my selected object?
2. How can i get the parameter in the DetailViewModel from ListViewModel

In my ListViewModel i've used

```
                INavigationService.NavigateToViewModel<DetailViewModel>(p_SelectedItem);
```

supposing that works not only with object like string..

and i get it in my DetailViewModel using

```
public Person Parameter { get; set; }
```

...but, it doesn't work...
could someone help me??
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**
I solved in this way

```
 <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Parameter}"  Margin="40" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="35"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}" FontSize="35"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontSize="35"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sex}" FontSize="35"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

It Works...but...is it correct?

Thanks